# How to set View Bounds for on HERE map using HERE-sdk of android?

Tags: android, maps, here-api, here-maps-rest

I have used view bounds in google maps before, to display a particular region in the Google maps. Now I have shifted my project to HERE maps. Can anyone help me replicating the same in HERE maps?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is too generic I suggest you to first ölook at the numerous examples provided by Here in github https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples. You can specifically look at map-objects project to see how map view is used. Hope this helps! Happy Coding!